# Remove item from ListView using onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

**Propose again my question. Sorry for the repetition.**

I have a ListView where there are all the applications installed on the device. At the click on the item, part of the uninstall. So far everything works fine, the problem is that once the application is uninstalled, then it is no longer on the device, it remains in the list. Obviously this is not good and therefore I wrote this code to try to remove it once it has been uninstalled.

```
int position;
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
            { 
            int requestCode = 1;
                app = appInfoArrayList.get(position);
                Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:"+app.packagename);
                //In theory i should put
                //this.position=position;
                //But Eclipse says "position cannot be resolved or is not a field"
                Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageUri);
                startActivityForResult(uninstallIntent, requestCode);
            }

    });   

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {

        String msg = "MyApp: ";
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == 1)
            {

                 try {
                     packageInfo = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(app.packagename, 0);
                 }
                 catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                     Log.v("Catch",msg );          
                     appInfoArrayList.remove(position);
                     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  
                 }

                }

            else {

            }

            Log.v(msg, String.valueOf(resultCode)+", "+String.valueOf(requestCode));

    }
```

In the LogCat i read: MyApp: Catch 0 (resultCode) , 1 (requestCode) So this means that enters correctly in the catch, but despite this, even if the application has been uninstalled is still on the list. Ideas on how I can fix this? Thanks in advance.

Adapter declaration

```
AppAdapter adapter;
```

Comment: can you log and tell the value of `position`? is it same as the one you are trying to remove.. because you never seem to update the value of `position`

Comment: this.position=position; it should be yourclassname.this.position=position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `position` in `appInfoArrayList.remove(position);` is uninitialized   make sure that you assign value to it.

Comment: That's right, the problem is just that. I should use this.position = position in the onItemClick method but Eclipse marks errors. How can I fix?

Comment: Declare a variable in class scope like  int mPosition; then  mPosition = position; in OnItemClickListener, then  in catch block  appInfoArrayList.remove(mPosition);

Answer (score 0):

You should redraw the list, call the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after renewing the adapter data source, this should solve the problem if you use the same ArrayList to store and to show the data

Comment: he did what you asked beofre 
appInfoArrayList.remove(position);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: This sort of answer (stating the obvious) is not really helpful!

Comment: i saw you did, i guess you are not using the same ArrayList to store the data and to display it.Could you post the adapter initialisation?

Comment: That's right. As he said Basbous I've done this thing that you suggested but it does not work. I think the problem is in the position variable.

Comment: Also this.postion=position will give you error, because this points to Listener object and not to the main class object, so you don't have the object in your listener. it should be only position=position,and int position should be a class field and not a local parameter

Answer (score 0):

You are using this on exception

```
appInfoArrayList.remove(position);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This should get called correctly to reflect the changes , check the data